# Computing a conditional gaussian distribution based on time-series model

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm currently working through this book: https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf and I am stuck on the following question:

**Question:**

Consider the time-series model
$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{x}_{t+1} &=\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}_t+\boldsymbol{w}, \quad \boldsymbol{w} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{Q}) \\
\boldsymbol{y}_t &=\boldsymbol{C} \boldsymbol{x}_t+\boldsymbol{v}, \quad \boldsymbol{v} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{R}),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{w}, \boldsymbol{v}$ are i.i.d. Gaussian noise variables. Further, assume that $p\left(\boldsymbol{x}_0\right)=$ $\mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}_0, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0\right)$

a. What is the form of $p\left(\boldsymbol{x}_0, \boldsymbol{x}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{x}_T\right)$ ? Justify your answer (you do not have to explicitly compute the
joint distribution). \

b. Assume that $p\left(\boldsymbol{x}_t \mid \boldsymbol{y}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{y}_t\right)=\mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}_t, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_t\right)$.

1. Compute $p\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{t+1} \mid \boldsymbol{y}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{y}_t\right)$.
2. Compute $p\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{t+1}, \boldsymbol{y}_{t+1} \mid \boldsymbol{y}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{y}_t\right)$.
3. At time $t+1$, we observe the value $\boldsymbol{y}_{t+1}=\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}$. Compute the conditional distribution $p\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{t+1} \mid \boldsymbol{y}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{y}_{t+1}\right)$.

**My attempt:**

For a. I know that applying a linear transformation to a gaussian and adding a gaussian to another gaussian, also results in a gaussian distribution.

Still I am uncertain, any help would be appreciated.